# Is it possible that .htaccess login method is blocked in China?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, great-firewall-of-china

I am currently building a small portal for an organisation to store some very basic confidential info (but not terribly important/secret). The staff are worldwide.

I initially decided to just use a basic .htaccess method (*with* https) but one person in China says they can't login (the domain itself is *not* blocked from China though).

Does anyone know if this is likely a normal thing/protocol that gets blocked in China? It seems a very basic thing to block and I am not sure how it would be blocked if the actual domain works...

i.e. In other words, is it possible to block htaccess logins at domains that are themselves not blocked?

In seeking this answer I am just trying to establish the likely cause of why they can't use the site (i.e. either blocked or not working for some other unknown reason).

Comment: HTTP Auth is just based on some specific HTTP headers and response codes. Those _could_ get blocked specifically while letting other requests through - but I think that is rather unlikely. Investigating this should start by getting a better problem description from the affected user, than just “can’t login”.

Comment: Thank you! I will post an update if I get more based on this.